# bsxfun error when perform '@minus'

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have two matrices to be subtracted. Let's see the code below.

```
A=rand(5472,1);
B=rand(1,3);

C= bsxfun(@minus, A, B(:))
```

I get the error saying that

> Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other

Any idea why this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to apply `bsxfun` on two column vectors, while you should apply it on one row and one column vector.

`bsxfun` inputs should have *different* singelton dimensions (`size(arr,dim) == 1`). in your example `size(A) = [5472,1]` and `size(B) = [1,3]` which is appropriate input (`A`'s singelton dimension is 2 and `B`'s singelton dimension is 1), but when you do `B(:)` - `B`'s singelton dimension becomes 2, like `A`'s, which throws an error.

do:

```
A=rand(5472,1);
B=rand(1,3);

C= bsxfun(@minus, A, B)
```

Comment: Can't believe I make such mistake! Thank you!